# Forward imputation in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

As a minimal example, say I have a tensor of the form:

```
[[ 1.   0.   3. ]
 [ 7.   5.   6. ]
 [ 0.   0.   0. ]
 [ 0.  11.   1. ]
 [ 0.   0.   0. ]
 [ 0.   0.   0. ]
 [13.  14.  16.5]]
```

Is there a way (natively in tensorflow) to impute the fully zeroed rows such their values are assigned to be equal to the last non-fully zeroed row? I.e. ->:

```
[[ 1.   0.   3. ]
 [ 7.   5.   6. ]
 [ 7.   5.   6. ]
 [ 0.  11.   1. ]
 [ 0.  11.   1. ]
 [ 0.  11.   1. ]
 [13.  14.  16.5]]
```

I thought about using `tf.tensor_scatter_nd_update` but with no success.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `tf.gather(a, indices)` to get the above output.

The `indices` needs to be `[0, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 6]` which can be be obtained with the following code:

```
mask = tf.cast(tf.cast(tf.reduce_sum(a, axis=1), dtype=tf.bool), tf.float32)
#[1., 1., 0., 1., 0., 0., 1.] where non-zero sum
mask_range = (mask*tf.range(a.shape[0], dtype=tf.float32))
#[0., 1., 0., 3., 0., 0., 6.] apply mask on range()
indices =tf.cast(tf.scan(lambda a, b: tf.maximum(a, b), mask_range, initializer=tf.reduce_min(mask_range)), tf.int32)
# cumulative max [0, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 6]

tf.gather(a, indices)
```

> ```
> [[ 1. ,  0. ,  3. ],
>  [ 7. ,  5. ,  6. ],
>  [ 7. ,  5. ,  6. ],
>  [ 0. , 11. ,  1. ],
>  [ 0. , 11. ,  1. ],
>  [ 0. , 11. ,  1. ],
>  [13. , 14. , 16.5]]
> ```

Answer (score 1):

This code can also be run on GPU too.

```
data = tf.constant([[ 1.,   0.,   3. ],
                    [ 7.,   5.,   6. ],
                    [ 0.,   0.,   0. ],
                    [ 0.,  11.,   1. ],
                    [ 0.,   0.,   0. ],
                    [ 0.,   0.,   0. ],
                    [13.,  14.,  16.5]])
rows_length = data.shape[-1]
```

```
i = tf.constant(0)
c = lambda i: tf.less(i, len(data))
tf.while_loop(c, find_zeros_and_update, [i])
```

```
def find_zeros_and_update(i):
    global _data
    if(i == 0):
        _data = data
    if(tf.reduce_sum(_data[i]) == 0):
        rows = tf.ones(shape=(rows_length,1), dtype=tf.int32) + (i-1)
        columns = tf.split(tf.range(0,rows_length),rows_length)
        indices = tf.concat((rows , columns), axis=1)
        update = _data[i-1]
        _data = tf.tensor_scatter_nd_update(_data, indices, update,)
    return (tf.add(i,1),)
```

Output:

```
<tf.Tensor: shape=(7, 3), dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[ 1. ,  0. ,  3. ],
       [ 7. ,  5. ,  6. ],
       [ 7. ,  5. ,  6. ],
       [ 0. , 11. ,  1. ],
       [ 0. , 11. ,  1. ],
       [ 0. , 11. ,  1. ],
       [13. , 14. , 16.5]], dtype=float32)>
```